# Elementwise subraction, of sorts, between two matrices

Tags: r, matrix

I really didn't know how to title this!

I'm trying to implement the formula below in R. You can pretty much ignore everything except for the summation part above the line

[image]

If I have two matrices

```
    > task2
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    3
[2,]    2    5    1

> actor
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    5    1
[2,]    2    4    6
[3,]    4    3    4
```

The resultant matrix should be (for the summation part above the line)

```
> result
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    0    0
[2,]    4    1    1
```

result[1,1] = sum(pmax(0,1-1),pmax(0,3-2),pmax(0,3-4) = 1

I think I know how to do it using nested for loops, though I know that is not how you would do it in R. This isn't correct but it should be along the lines of this

```
for (i in 1:nrow(task)){
  for (j in 1:ncol(actor)){
    for (k in 1:ncol(task)){
      result[i,j] <- sum(pmax(0,(task[i,k]-actor[k,j))
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to attack this problem?

Comment: Check the desired output again. Please explain how `result[1,3]` became `1` when the formula you provided results in `sum(pmax(0,1-1),pmax(0,3-6),pmax(0,3-4)) = 0`

Comment: Sorry I calculated it in my head. Thanks for spotting it.

Comment: The second row is off too. `results[2,1]` should be `sum(pmax(0,2-1),pmax(0,5-2),pmax(0,1-4)) = 4`. How do you expect people to help you when you can't even be bothered to write up an example? And take out the picture, it isn't helping.

Comment: Again apologies for that. When I was creating the matrix I never created it by rows. I assumed it was correct without checking before pasting. I will leave the picture in though, it gives some context to what I'm trying to do. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the logic you present in the example, this should work. Please check your desired output against the formula you cited. Accurate results depend on the first *mxn* matrix to be compared to a *nxp* matrix so that the columns of matrix one are equal to the rows of matrix two:

```
t(apply(task2, 1, function(x) {
  colSums(matrix(pmax(0,x-actor), ncol=ncol(task2)))
}))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    0    0
# [2,]    4    1    1
```

**update**

To explain what the function is doing it helps to run it one line at a time:

```
#The generalized function
function(x) {
  colSums(matrix(pmax(0,x-actor), ncol=ncol(task2)))
}
```

Applied to the first row only by replacing `task2[1,]` where `x` was:

```
colSums(matrix(pmax(0, task2[1,] - actor), ncol=ncol(task2)))
[1] 1 0 0
```

We are creating a new matrix and taking the column sums. Let's see it in more detail. At the core of the function we are comparing the first row of `task2` to the matrix `actor`:

```
task2[1,] - actor
     X..1. X..2. X..3.
[1,]     0    -4     0
[2,]     1    -1    -3
[3,]    -1     0    -1
```

This is the most important part. It subtracts the matrices as desired. All of the rest of the code is a way to make it look nice.

When we add `pmax` the nice matrix that we have above turns into a single vector:

```
pmax(0, task2[1,] - actor)
[1] 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The numbers are correct but we can not get the sum of each column while it looks like that. So we turn it into a matrix with the same number of columns with:

```
matrix(pmax(0, task2[1,] - actor), ncol=ncol(task2))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    1    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0
```

Now it is in the form that we need. But we only need the sums of each column, so we add `colSums`:

```
colSums(matrix(pmax(0, task2[1,] - actor), ncol=ncol(task2)))
[1] 1 0 0
```

Comment: If you get a chance, would you mind explaining how function(x) works. I thought I understood it but I can't seem to get my head around it.

Comment: I added a detailed explanation

Comment: Wonderful, I appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

Define a generalized inner product.  For example, if `f <- function(x, y) sum(x*y)` then it defines matrix multiplication.

```
inner <- function(a,b,f) {
    f <- match.fun(f)
    apply(b,2,function(x)apply(a,1,function(y)f(y,x)))
}
```

Now use it with the appropriate function:

```
inner(task2, actor, function(x, y) sum(pmax(0, x - y)))
```

giving:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    0    0
[2,]    4    1    1
```

Comment: It certainly looks nice! Like Pierre's answer, could you explain what function(y)f(y,x) is doing? I'd love to get a better understanding of functions

Comment: The outer `apply`  is applied to each column (dimension 2) of `b` and within  the function so applied is an inner `apply` which applies over the rows (dimension 1) of `a` using the value of `x` from the function in the outer `apply`.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation. I'm still getting the hang of more advanced apply functions